# Need to check if this function is bijective

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I don't understand how $f : \mathbb N \to\mathbb N$ (where $0$ isn't included in the natural numbers set), $f(n) = n^2$ is not bijective. It seems both injective and surjective to me?

Thanks got it!

Comment: For which $n$ is $f(n) = 3$?

Answer (score 3):

It is surely not a surjection onto $\mathbb N$. For example, there is no n such that f(n) = 2.

Answer (score 2):

We can only find $n$ such that $f(n)$ is a square number. Can we find an $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $f(n)$ is **not** a square number? Of course not! What does this imply about surjectivity? What does the definition of a bijection (injection+surjection) now tell us?

Answer (score 2):

It seems as though your notion of surjective is off. A function $f : X \rightarrow Y $ is surjective if and only if $\forall y \in Y$, $\exists x \in X$ such that $f(x) = y$. That is to say the set being mapped to gets completely "covered" by the map. In your case $\mathbb{N}$ does not get "covered" by the map.